# What does the `if` modifier in `my` statement?

Tags: perl

The following minimal code example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub f {
    my ( $c ) = @_;
    my $n = 1 if 0;
    $n or $n = $c if $c;
    printf "%s\n", $n;
}

f( 3 );
f( 4 );
```

for me calculates

> 3

> 3

However, if I replace the `if`-modified `my` statement in the code and run

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub f {
    my ( $c ) = @_;
    my $n;
    $n or $n = $c if $c;
    printf "%s\n", $n;
}

f( 3 );
f( 4 );
```

then I get

> 3

> 4

My first thought was that the conditional modifier would dupe `strict` and then `$n` would sometimes refer to a global. But the behaviour of the first snippet does not change if I drop `use strict` and define `$n = 6;` or `my $n = 6;` or `our $n = 6;` upfront before `sub f`.

What is happening here?

Comment: `perlsyn` says: NOTE: The behaviour of a my, state, or our modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, my $x if ...) is undefined. The value of the my variable may be undef, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it. Future versions of perl might do something different from the version of perl you try it out on. Here be dragons. 
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn

Comment: @ernix: That should be an answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson The words "Here be dragons" in perlsyn is a bit too noncommittal and it explains nothing.  I'd rather prefer to know the background behind these rules.

Comment: @ernix I'd say "the behaviour ... is undefined" is clear enough. But the question has been closed as a duplicate (with answers to the duplicate questions citing the same wording), so you can't post an answer anyway.